# How do I diagnose overheating?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, fan, overheating, diagnostic

I use my computer mainly for gaming, and recently I've been having issues with various games crashing. I suspected my video card as I got errors of the kind "Your rendering device has been lost" in Overwatch and plain freezing in Witcher 3. I reverted to older graphics card drivers, and now the computer shuts down instead of crashing individual applications. No BSOD or helpful logs are generated.

I suspect overheating, so I downloaded HWMonitor to watch the temperature and fan speeds. The temperature rises for both CPU and graphics card, and the fans increase in RPM, but I can't hear any fans turning on. It's completely silent. I suspect the fans simply don't turn on, even though the software side seems to think it does. Interestingly, I *can* hear the fans turn on at seemingly random times during heavy load usage, so I know I should be able to hear *something*. Unsure if it's the graphics card, the CPU cooling or both turning on though.

My computer is a bit of a Frankenstein as I bought it in parts around 2009 and have upgraded bits and pieces at a time. The oldest parts are the motherboard and the CPU, everything else has been upgraded (PSU, cooling, case, storage units, video card, memory, peripherals). Could this be a sign of my motherboard giving up?

Mobo: ASUS P6T Deluxe V2

CPU: Intel i7 920

Graphics: NVIDIA GTX 760

Memory: 12 GB

OS: Windows 10 64 bit Education

I'll be happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: There is a very easy way to know whether the fans are actually on: open your computer, start it and look. Use this occasion to give a good cleaning to your computer, as dust is often the cause of blocked fans. If they don't turn on, even after cleaning, consider replacing them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the PC Operating Temperatures.
after that open your computer, and with soft brush clean all the fans (use cold hair dryer to take the dust out)
highly recommend to replace your Thermal grease on the CPU (buy one from ebay).

Comment: why would you replace the thermal paste without any kind of indication that it's necessary?

Comment: Intel Core i7 920 was released in November 2008.
The motherboard in 2010. after so many years, I think he should clean it and use new.

Comment: I've used both HWMonitor and SpeedFan to monitor temperatures, and the CPU can go up to about 80 or 90 during heavy usage. Ealier this spring, I bought a new case and cleaned the inside and replaced the thermal paste. CPU fan is a fairly constant value, for the record.

Comment: what was the highest temperature?

Comment: @user93114 is that with 100% RPM? Because my overclocked 5820k just hits 80°C (with 80% RPM), so I'd think this looks like you didn't properly apply the paste (far too little/far too much - or some air inside). And this is the case in my point: if temperatures are good, one shouldn't replace thermal paste - best it can do is to go wrong. *(However, 80-90°C isn't what I'd consider good)*

Comment: @F.Rahamim I can't recall, but definitively more than 80°C. Probably not more than 90°C.

Comment: @flolilolilo Not sure, how do I view the % RPM? The CPU fan hasn't moved above 1795 RPM during a recent gaming session, and it's currently at 1757 RPM (CPU at 38°C).

Comment: @user93114 speedfan can adjust/read the %-values - or perhaps you can manually set it to 100% in your bios. also, are you using a special application for that? because tools like prime tend to run around 10° hotter than the average program.

Comment: Not using any special applications for editing BIOS. Speedfan looks like this: [link](http://imgur.com/a/E0cFk). Does this imply my fans are at 100%?